# Bad value “” for attribute “href” on element “link”: Must be non-empty

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, w3c-validation

I have a Ruby on Rails application and in the application.html.erb file I have CSS referenced as

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" media="print" id="print_css" href="#"  data-css-url=<%=stylesheet_url('print')%>>
```

But the W3C validator throws error as

> Bad value “” for attribute “href” on element “link”: Must be
>   non-empty.

So I can put `#` or `javascript:void` for the `href` value.

Which one makes sense here for `href` value?

Comment: Why do you have the URL on the data attribute instead of the href?

Answer (score 0):

```
javascript:void
```

Will be right approach as it will not let validator follow any URL and implicitly telling bot or browser that don't follow anything.